# Matlab "for loop" to create a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a fairly large vector named `blender`. I have extracted `n` elements for which `blender` is greater than `x` (irrelevant). Now my difficulty is the following:

I am trying to create a (`21 x n`) matrix with each element of blender plus 10 things before, and the 10 things after.

```
element=find(blender >= 120);
```

I have been trying variations of the following:

```
for i=element(1:end)
    Matrix(i)= Matrix(blender(i-10:i+10));
end
```

then I want to plot one column of the matrix at the time when I hit Enter. 
This second part I can figure out later, but I would appreciate some help making the Matrix

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First, you can use "logical indexing" of your array, which uses a logical expression do address your vector. With `blender = [2, 302, 35, 199, 781, 312, 8]`, it could look like this:

```
>> b_hi = blender(blender>=120)
b_hi =
       302  199  781  312
```

Second, you can concatenate arrays like in `b_padded = [1, 2, b_hi, 3, 4]`. If `b_hi` was a column vector, you'd use semicolons instead of commas.

Third, there is a function `reshape` that allows you to turn the resulting vector into a matrix. `doc reshape` will tell you details. For example, to turn `b_padded` into a 2-by-4 matrix,

```
>> b_matrix = reshape(b_padded, 4, 2)
b_matrix =
           1   302   781     3
           2   199   312     4
```

will do. This means you can do all of the job without any for-loop. Note that transposing the result of `reshape(b_padded, 2, 4)` will give you the other possible 2-by-4 matrix. You obtain the transpose of a matrix `A` by `A'`. You will find out which one you want.

Comment: +1: obviously the OP is experiencing difficulties with vectorization. I suggest laying out the final solution for clarity.

Comment: I see, but how do I get the 10 before and after. Say bleder is 1:1:100.   And I extracted 60, also element 60. I want 50:70 as one column, then the 10 before and after of the second extracted element

Comment: I apologize I did not understand your question right. @shoelzer's approach is correct. If your index bounds are valid downwards, another problem to consider is the upper bound. See comment below.

Comment: I don't understand how indexing is even a problem since `k` is an element number (integer and positive from 608 to 22,543), `blender` is my raw data, 0 from up to 153.7444

Comment: @shoelzer's point is that `blender` may be less than 22,543 + 10 = 22,553 long. What is `length(blender)`?

Comment: `length(blender)` = 76,959

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new matrix, and use two indices so that Matlab knows it is assigning to a column in a 2D matrix.

```
NewMatrix = zeros(21, length(element));
for i = 1:length(element)
    k = element(i);
    NewMatrix(:,i)= Matrix(blender(k-10:k+10));
end
```

Comment: I understand this answer the most. When I try to run it I get "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

Comment: I'm guessing that `k-10` ends up being negative so it's not a valid index. You need to decide what should happen in that case.

Comment: No, the smallest k I have is 608, I even tried with blender(k:k+10), same error.

Comment: Then maybe the values in `blender` are not valid indices for `Matrix`.

Comment: that could be it, since blender does not have integers

Comment: +1, @shoelzer. Idea to avoid those out of bounds errors could be to kick out elements before matrix construction as in `element(element < 11) = []` but also consider the upper bound by `element(element > length(blender) - 10) = []`.

Comment: @s.bandara Good idea, but the OP needs to decide if that is valid to do for this problem or not. I'm going to leave it out.